# How change Android spinner prompt background color

Tags: android, spinner, prompt

Hi I want to change the background color of Android spinner prompt or title, not the background color of Spinner List item.
So far I have not yet found any effective way to do it.
Thanks.

Comment: Try to use custom xml layout for your spinner layout

Comment: May I know the detail pls? As there is no such attribute to define it. thx

Comment: Can you show a sample of what you've tried so far?